# SSL read is throwing error "cipher text sanity check fail"

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a C++ SSL server and a Java windows client trying to connect to it by TLSv1. (jre used is 1.6)

Through openssl command I am connecting to sever which is showing logs fine (as attached),

but when I am trying to connect through windows client ,it is throwing error.

> "ciphertext sanity check fails'

Please if you can help what can be probable caused of this ?

This doesnot happen when server is TLSv1+SSLv3 enabled ,but when i disable SSLv3 this message starts coming .

Comment: Here is openssl command logs :

Comment: The sited string *“cipher text sanity check fail”* returns one hit during search, and its this question. I've worked with OpenSSL for years, and I have never encountered the message. I'm guessing that's not the real error message; or you are using a library that you have not told us about.